# Shiny, reuss reactive input pickerInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create my first shiny app but I am facing a difficulty: in the reproducible example below I am creating a reactive pickerInput (i.e. only show brands proposing a cylindre equal to the input visitors select).

I then want that based on the combination `input_cyl` and `picker_cny` (remember that `picker_cny` depends on `input_cyl`) to display a table which shows the relevant data for the observation matching the combination `input_cyl` and `picker_cny`.

Thank you for your help!

```
df <- mtcars
df$brand <- rownames(mtcars)
df$brand <- gsub("([A-Za-z]+).*", "\\1", df$brand)

if (interactive()) {

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinycssloaders)

# Define UI -----------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Reproducible Example"),

  # Parameters
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "input_cyl", label = "Cyl",
                  choices = c("6", "4", "8")),
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "picker_cny",
        label = "Select Company",
        choices = paste0(unique(df$brand)),
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        multiple = TRUE),
      width = 2),
    
    # Show Text
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table"),
      width = 10)
  ))


# Define Server ------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive pickerInput ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$input_cyl, {
    
    df_mod <- df[df$cyl == paste0(input$input_cyl), ]
    
    # Method 1
    disabled_choices <- !df$cyl %in% df_mod$cyl
    updatePickerInput(session = session, 
                      inputId = "picker_cny",
                      choices = paste0(unique(df$brand)),
                      choicesOpt = list(
                        disabled = disabled_choices,
                        style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                                       yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                       no = "")
                      ))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  output$table <- renderTable(df)
  }
} 


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reactive that will handle the change in the input and subset the dataframe before giving it to the output table. For that, you just need to add this block to your server:

```
    data <- reactive({
        if (length(input$picker_cny) > 0)
            df[df$brand %in% input$picker_cny,]
        else 
            df
    })
```

and update the `output$table` like this:

```
    output$table <- renderTable(data())
```

Note: feel free to remove the `if else` in the reactive to get that:

```
    data <- reactive({
        df[df$brand %in% input$picker_cny,]
    })
```

The only difference in that case is: would you show all or nothing when no input has been entered yet. That's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, it worked fine! As a side question, if I want to assign an ID to what is being selected in picker_cny can I do something like ```choices = c(paste0(unique(df$brand)) = paste0(unique(df$brand_id))),```. Assuming that band_id is a unique identifier for Mazda and so on